# View integer on memory locations allocated as char in Visual C++ 2008 debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, debugging, pointers, visual-c++-2008

I'm using Visual C++ 2008 to write and debug my project. I have a char* pointer. I want to view 4 bytes starting at my pointer as an integer in the debugger. How do I do it? (int)(*pointer) comes to mind but I'm afraid it will simply take the 1-byte value pointed to by pointer and convert it to an integer.

Comment: @KerrekSB automatically converted to comment?

Comment: @KerrekSB well, it's the correct answer :)

Comment: It is the correct answer. Thanks. Please add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: OK, posted! Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: Also, if you don't already know this, you can view multiple elements in an array (or from a pointer) with `,`. i.e. `char* x;`. If you add a watch on `x`, you can write `x,4` and it will display the first 4 elements of x.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, Luchian. I'm using Express edition so this might be the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to cast your pointer to the desired pointer type and *then* dereference, like so:

```
*(int*)(pointer)
```

This works in GDB, though I imagine it's similar in other debuggers.